# Custom Flutter TabBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, tabbar

How to implement this design (one way and round trip) in Flutter, while incorporating the existing TabBar functionalities?

[image]

Comment: The TabBar you're talking about is the "Economy/Premium/Business/First Class" or the "One Way/Round Trip"?

Comment: One Way and roundtrip

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code producing a very close result. Basically, it uses CustomPainter to draw the required styles on top of TabBar. I've come up with all numbers for geometry myself but you might try to deduct some clean formulas for production code. Also, I only did CustomPainter for one state but you can create two and switch between them based on your TabController state.

[image]

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("EXAMPLE"),
      ),
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 300,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              color: Colors.grey[200],
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    CustomPaint(
                      size: const Size(double.infinity, 50),
                      painter: BorderPainter(),
                    ),
                    const TabBar(
                      labelColor: Colors.blue,
                      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                      indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(icon: Text('One Way')),
                        Tab(icon: Text('Round Trip')),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 300,
                  child: TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      Icon(CupertinoIcons.arrow_right),
                      Icon(CupertinoIcons.arrow_2_circlepath),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BorderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double strokeWidth = 1.5;

    var paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    canvas.drawArc(
      const Offset(1, 1) & const Size(20, 20),
      pi,
      pi / 2,
      false,
      paint,
    );
    canvas.drawLine(
      const Offset(10, 1),
      Offset(size.width / 2 - 20, 1),
      paint,
    );
    canvas.drawArc(
      Offset(size.width / 2 - 22, 1) & const Size(5, 5),
      3 * pi / 2,
      pi / 4,
      false,
      paint,
    );
    canvas.drawLine(
      Offset(size.width / 2 - 17, 2.5),
      Offset(size.width / 2 + 20, size.height - 2.5),
      paint,
    );
    canvas.drawArc(
      Offset(size.width / 2 + 20, size.height - 6) & const Size(5, 5),
      pi / 2,
      pi / 4,
      false,
      paint,
    );
    canvas.drawLine(
      Offset(size.width / 2 + 23.5, size.height - 1),
      Offset(size.width - 10, size.height - 1),
      paint,
    );
    canvas.drawArc(
      Offset(size.width - 21, size.height - 1) & const Size(20, 20),
      3 * pi / 2,
      pi / 2,
      false,
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```